# After fadeIn other element slides down

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

id like to know if its possible to make with css3 transition , that element is sliding down, after another fadesIn. 
Heres fiddle, so may makes it more clear ;) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCT8F/)

Id like this `#text` to slide down after image fades in not just jumps down ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css

```
#container img{
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;    
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
#container img.shown {
    max-height: 20em;
}
```

js

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#container img").addClass('shown');
},1500);
```

html not changed

unfortunatelly you can't animate `max-height` to the value `auto`, so you have to choose reasonable max-height after the picture is revealed

Comment: Also this won't give that animation effect in IE < 10.

Comment: he wanted CSS3 solution, this is CSS3... and IE sucks :)

Comment: awesome, thanks ;) And thanks for IE advice, however i dont care about IE ;p ill just make it static if some still uses that (is rly some1 there ? )xD

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function() {

    $("#container img").fadeIn(1300, function() { 

        $("#text").slideDown(200); 

    });

}, 1500);
```

**CSS**

```
#text{
   display:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wCT8F/6/)**

Comment: Where should it slide down from if is not slid up?

Comment: @dollarVar since `#text` has the css `display:none;` it has the dimensions 0x0 (it's hidden). Now when you call `slideDown()` on it, it gradually get it's "natural" height and get's visible.

Comment: Tank you for your answer, however i wanted to know css3 solution ;)

Comment: Display: none; Turns off the display of an element (it has no effect on layout); all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element did not exist. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display . Visibilty: hidden; The hidden value hides an element but leaves space where it would have been. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to detach the #text div from the flow of the DOM. With the current way it is set up, the text will always be affected by the image. In order to transition it separately, you'l l need to CSS the text to be absolute, and then slide it down in the fadeIn callback:

```
setTimeout(function () {

   $("#container img").fadeIn(1300, function () {
       $("#text").animate({
           top: '125px'
       }, 1000);
   });

}, 1500);
```

Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCT8F/5/)

Comment: Tank you for your answer, however i wanted to know css3 solution ;) i know how to animate with jquery ;)